# how this website is hiding all in inspect elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, browser, code-inspection

I have been through a website

It had blocked F12,Ctrl+shift+I,right click

So I tried from options->More Settings-> Developer Tools

But still, the elements tab is empty? Why or how is it doing this?

site : `https://uplod.net/ahfdhke06rhca656yw0e`

[image]

Comment: It keeps changing its content so the dev tools are basically refreshing constantly I guess.

Comment: It's trapping me in the debugger. I'm using chrome

Comment: As soon as the page loads all I get is " Oops..! Failed to load data. Try a different browser."

Comment: its due to adblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not well formatted, but I captured this by curling the url.

```
function disable_developer_tool(){
  let checkStatus;
hotkeys("command+option+j,command+option+i,command+shift+c,command+option+c,command+option+k,command+option+z,command+option+e,f12,ctrl+shift+i,ctrl+shift+j,ctrl+shift+c,ctrl+shift+k,ctrl+shift+e,shift+f7,shift+f5,shift+f9,shift+f12",
(
  function(e,t){e.preventDefault()
}));
let element=new Image;
Object.defineProperty(element,"id",{
  get:function(){
    throw checkStatus="on",new Error("Dev tools checker")
  }
}),
requestAnimationFrame((function check({
  checkStatus="off",
  console.dir(element),
  "on"===checkStatus?(document.body.parentNode.removeChild(document.body),document.head.parentNode.removeChild(document.head),setTimeout((function(){for(;;)eval("debugger")}),100)):requestAnimationFrame(check)}))}
```

This watches for events that would open the developer console and deletes all the elements and drops the debugger into an endless loop. It looks like it's attached to the mdpUnGrabber library which attempts to kill adblock.

Here's an article about it. https://ibug.io/blog/2020/08/work-against-wordpress-deblocker/

Comment: also possible to just view the source of the page. You have to go through the browser menus - Tools -> Web Developer -> Page Source. Or just type in `view-source:<url>` in the URL bar (works in Chrome, too). Also possible to save the page to your local machine. This also downloads all referenced resources like stylesheets, images, and .js files.

Comment: I'f I just viewed the source of the page how would I be able to grep the debugger call? Seems like a lot of work.

Comment: My point was just to mention some simple alternatives that can still get the same result. Because I thought it might be mildly useful for somebody else but I also didn't feel needed a whole answer about it. Yet you seem unnecessarily defensive over that.

Comment: Fair enough, I felt like you were calling me out. I probably overreacted.